# negative constant converted to unsigned type error in c++ by using visual studio how to solve

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, type-conversion

my C++ program is running well on dev c++ compiler. But now I want to run it win32 console on visual studio 2013 but I am getting an error: **negative constant converted to unsigned type**

Could you please tell me how to solve it?

```
void modifystudent(int id) 
{   
    fstream file;   
    file.open("users11.txt",ios::in | ios::out);
    student obj;    
    system("cls");
    while (file.read((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj)))     
    {       
        if (obj.givid() ==id)       
        {           
            cout << "\nPlease enter new details of student";
            obj.getrecord();   //// error is here negative constant converted to unsigned type          
            int pos = -1 * sizeof(obj);
            file.seekp(pos, ios::cur);
            file.write((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj));           
            cout << endl << " Record is Modified.." << endl;        
        }   
    }

    file.close();   
   // free(obj);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both gcc and VS give warnings here. The reason you get error under VS is because you probably have enabled `/WX` option which treats warnings as errors. The simple solution is to cast `sizeof(obj)` to int before multiplication:

```
int pos = -1 * static_cast<int>(sizeof(obj));
```

---

Longer explanation:

In this expression:

```
int pos = -1 * sizeof(obj);
```

`-1` is of type `int`, and `sizeof(obj)` is of type `size_t`, and all we know about `size_t` is that it is unsigned integer - I suppose mostly it will be 4 or 8 bytes wide. Compiler will try to transform both operands to a common type before making multiplication, those conversions are implicit.

Now to the conversion rule which applies here: when signed integer is multiplied with unsigned, and the unsigned operand is the same as or larger that that of the signed operand, the signed operand is converted to unsigned.

So if `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes, and `sizeof(size_t)` is 8 bytes then `-1` is first converted to `static_cast<size_t>(-1)` which is equal to `0xffffffffffffffff`. Then multiplication is done, and after that another conversion is applied - the result of multiplication is converted to int. Because `sizeof(obj)` is known at compile time, compiler will know the exact value, if `sizeof(obj)` is 1 then the result of multiplication is `0xffffffffffffffff` and its too large to be assigned to `int` variable without truncation so compiler warns you about the implicit conversion which is required.

Depending on `size_t` size, compilers gives different warnings here:

clang informs of the last phase when result of multiplication is converted to int (x64 compilation, sizeof(size_t)==8):

```
main.cpp:15:17: warning: implicit conversion from 'unsigned long' to 'int' changes value from 18446744073709551615 to -1 [-Wconstant-conversion]
   int pos = -1 * sizeof(obj);
       ~~~   ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

(18446744073709551615 is 0xffffffffffffffff)

gcc looks similar but is less informative (x64 compilation, sizeof(size_t)==8):

```
main.cpp:16:29: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
    int pos = -1 * sizeof(obj);
```

Visual Studio 2015 on the other hand warns about conversion of -1 to unsigned type (in x86 build, sizeof(size_t)==4):

```
warning C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type
```

I suppose it informs about this conversion `static_cast<size_t>(-1)`.

and in x64 (sizeof(size_t)==8) about truncation of constant value (the same warning as above gcc and clang shows)

```
warning C4309: 'initializing': truncation of constant value
```

but for some reason C4308 is no longer shown, even tho -1 is still being converted to unsigned integral.

Comment: thank you so much sir, Marcin. but now program run but between the program abnormal termination is happening.. thanks you explain this thing with so much details. thanks for sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace

```
int pos = -1 * sizeof(obj);
```

by

```
int pos = -1 * (int)sizeof(obj);
```

Comment: thank you so much sir, michael walz. but now program run but between the program abnormal termination is happening..

Comment: That's another problem. Maybe because file `users11.txt` could not be opened and you don't check if `file.open` succeeds.

Comment: sir it is adding record nicely, but when every i modify record or show record that time it terminate, and give error that assertion failed.

Comment: sir is it the possibility that other functions are treating this object or means calculating the object size differently

Comment: @ishtiaq yes it is possible. This is a completly different problem, please narrow down the problem, possibly by using a debugger, and then ask another question.